# Custom 64bit 3.10.9 kernel not booting in qemu and stucks on Booting from ROM

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, make, qemu, boot-loader

My custom build kernel 4.10.9 with gcc-4.8 is not booting in qemu and it is stuck on booting from ROM:

[image]

I used the following qemu command: `qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel linux-3.10.9/arch/x86/boot/bzImage`.

(of course I selected [*] 64-bit kernel with `make menuconfig`)

Here is my config file: [.config](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OuDY-zI8uE8lUj2naJDAVuKSFbNd5Aea/view?usp=sharing)
I used `make -j 2` to compile it.