# Cannot get Qemu to move past "Booting from ROM"?

Tags: linux, boot, qemu

My custom build kernel 4.9.327 with gcc-11.2 is not booting in Qemu and it is stuck on "Booting from ROM".

Just like the screenshot here: [Custom 64bit 3.10.9 kernel not booting in qemu and stucks on Booting from ROM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625230/custom-64bit-3-10-9-kernel-not-booting-in-qemu-and-stucks-on-booting-from-rom)

I run qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel linux-4.9.327/arch/x86/boot/bzImage

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need

```
--append "console=tty0 console=ttyS0"
```

to redirect the output to you terminal like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel linux-4.9.327/arch/x86/boot/bzImage
-nographic --append "console=tty0 console=ttyS0"
```